# getting multiple attributes from a link before sending to a .load query

Tags: jquery

The code below is supposed to grab the ?cs=bla&cat=bla values from the link attribute and post it to my .load query...does anyone know where i am going wrong?

```
//Remove tab info and add gallery
    $(".more").click(function () {
        var $gallery = $(this).closest('.tab').find('.gallery-holder'),
        cat = $(this).attr('href').split('cat=')[1];
        if ($gallery.is(':empty')) {
        $gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat}, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(function(){
                $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); 
            });
        });
        }

        $gallery.siblings().fadeOut(function(){
            $gallery.fadeIn();
        });     
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your approach goes wrong is the split, when you do this: `.split('cs=')`, you're not getting `"bla"` as the result, you're getting `"bla&cat=bla"`, the rest of the string.

---

You could just pass the data as the same string if it's in a known format (the original querystring pairs), like this:

```
var data = this.href.split('?').pop();
if ($gallery.is(':empty')) {
  $gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', data, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(function() {
        $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); 
    });
  });
}
```

Note this would produce a GET request rather than a POST (which happens then [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) gets an object as the `data` argument).

Comment: does that send each one as $_POST['cs'] e.t.c?

Comment: There is an error in this line? var data = this.href.split('?').pop();

Comment: @Andy - What error are you getting? If this isn't an anchor you'll need `$(this).attr("href").split('?').pop();` for the invalid attribute :)

Comment: $(".more").click(function () {
  var $gallery = $(this).closest('.tab').find('.gallery-holder'),
  cat = $(this).attr('href').split('cat=')[1];
  cs = $(this).attr('href').split('cs=')[1];
  if ($gallery.is(':empty')) {
  $gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat, 'cs': cs}, function(){
   $(this).fadeIn(function(){
    $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); 
   });
  });
  }

Comment: @Andy -.... *what* error are you getting? you're not using my answer at all, you're still splitting invalidly and you'll have the same error you did with the code in the question...

Comment: Sorry Nick, check out my edit in the main question where i include the whole function, now you'll notice why i couldn't use the original answer without causing an error.  I should have included this at the start.  Apologies.

Comment: i just removed the comma and added a semi colon where it says find('.gallery-holder'), its working now :)  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Andy - Ah, I see what you're after, look here for a function to get a querystring out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery/901144#901144 just replace `window.location.href` with your own `href` attribute.